# Calling void methods in IIS 7 and not waiting for them to return

Tags: asp.net, iis, events, iis-7, multithreading

I'm on IIS7

I have a button on a page.

When I click it, a new thread is started which calls a void method, which takes 20 to 30 minutes to complete.

The problem is the called void method stops running as soon as control is returned to the browser. (At least it appears to)

```
 protected void _Build_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Build.IsBuilding) return;
            var t = new Thread(Build.DoBuild);
            t.Start();
        }
```

Should it behave this way or should control be returned to the browser and continue?
Is there another way to invoke a method and not wait for it to complete?

Comment: Why do you say that it appears to stop running? What have you observed? What are you trying to to in the thread?

Comment: It seems the thread that I started just ends as soon as control is returned to the page.

Comment: I'm trying to do something that takes a long time on the server (Build an Index)

Comment: What makes you think the thread has stopped running once control is returned to the page?  Make sure the method you're using for your thread catches and logs any exceptions somewhere so you're aware of them.  Maybe you're doing something that requires an active page context.

Comment: So starting the thread there, conceptually it should continue right? Assuming there's nothing wrong in the thread logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your method being stopped by script timeout. There are different ways to fix it:

1. Increase script timeout. I would not recommend this one, as the long operation locks Application pool thread and it can't process other requests. But you can try :) http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18803
2. Using asynchronous methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx
3. Workflows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.longrunwf.aspx
4. Execute your process with Ajax request to the web service and polling the service to check the execution status.